# Nodejs - How to find which router is used for a request?

Tags: node.js

I have an app that has very many routing functions, and today I add a new route:

`app.get(/^\/somepath/, newRouteFunc);`

When I test the app, `newRouteFunc` is not called. I guess it's due to the path is wrong, but how can I know which routing function is actually used by express?

Thank you.

Comment: Put a debugger into all of them:)

Comment: Well is there a smarter way?

Comment: nothing I can think of, only logging or debugging

Comment: Are you using Express ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put before it the `app.get('*', myFunc);` so it accepts everything. Then inside myFunc, if you define it as standard `(req, res, next)` you can log what you have inside `req`, where there is also the part URL this router knows (I think its `req.url`).

You can also check `req.route`

To debug express check the: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Comment: My question is in fact about "Which function does this URL go?", so I don't think this method helps :(

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai - updated answer with link that is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you very much.